# Visual Studio Code debugger attaches but does not stop node js process

Tags: node.js, vscode-debugger

I have a Node js application (running on Windows) which occasionally "hangs" - it gives no sign of progress. From Visual Studio Code, I attach the debugger by selecting the process ID. Evidence of successful attachment is given both from within VSC and standard out (console):

"Debugger listening on ws://x.y.z.1:9229/242f50ce-a43c-48dc-9926-23520ed10ed3
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached."

However, the process continues to run and clicking on the "pause" symbol in the debugger control bar un-ghosts momentarily but does not change to the "continue" symbol (other control symbols on the bar remain ghosted).

Launch configuration:

```
{
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
            "request": "attach",
            //"skipFiles": [
            //    "<node_internals>/**"
            //],
            "type": "node"
        },
    
        {
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
            "request": "launch",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "node", "args": ["set", "31100-1", "subsets" ]
        }
        ]
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast"
}
```

On occasion when I attach and then detach ("Stop Debugging") the process seems to continue and behave normally (no longer hung), but I am not able to discover where and/or why it is hanging.

I should add that while this Node js program runs from both a windows power shell and a Cygwin tcsh, it is when running from the Cygwin that I am seeing this behavior (insufficient testing from power shell to say whether or not this ever occurs)

I can understand that the source might not be visible from VSC or that the callstack would be abbreviated/incomplete, but I would expect the process to stop. Perhaps it has and I am misinterpreting the VSC presentation.

Any discussion or suggestions are welcomed. I am both a Node js and VSC novice.